# How to exit a while-loop with the value of an input which is inside another while-loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
loop1 = True
while loop1 == True:
info = input("option 1,2 or 3?")
if info == '1':
    print("while 1, option 1")
    loop2 = True
    while loop2 == True:
        again = input("1- again(while2) or 2- Close(while2)")
        if again == '1':
            info2 = input("info 2-")
        elif again == '2':
            print("Close!!!")
            loop2 == False
        else:
            print("ERRO! again")
            again = input("again? 2-")

elif info == '2':
    print("while 1, option 2")
elif info == '3':
    print("while 1, option3, Exit!")
    loop1 = False      
else:
    print("erro!")
    info = input("err! Can you tell me how much is the ")


print("I'm out!")
```

I'm new in python!
My goal is to get out of loop 2 with the value of info2 and enter loop1 with the value of info2 so that you can choose another option such as option 2 or 3.
I know I have to loop1 = loop2, but I do not know where to put the code

Comment: Could you please correct your indentation, not sure which parts is meant to be in loop 1 and 2. `print("I'm out")` is probably outside of the loops all together? Short answer tho, use different variables for the different inputs. And store them in a variable defined *before* both loops. That way it will "stick" throughout your program.

Comment: did you mean that you want to control loop2 with value of info2 in place of again?

Comment: I pretty much want to use the info2 input outside of the second while.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to begin by fixing your indentation... cant exit a sentinel while loop when the code to do so is outside both while loops. Id also recommend setting "universal" variables to manipulate each of the while loops, (when these variables overlap then you should be able to exit one when using another. Try using something other than boolean statements to declare each sentinal loops ( even simple strings would do better). If this is exercising your ability in using while loops than keep going with this method, but really python offers a lot easier ways to create this program.....